# What is meant by "attraction range" in image similarity?

Tags: medical-imaging, measurement, x-rays

I am reading [this article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/153303460700600411) about measuring similarity between x-rays and DRR's (2d projections from CT) and the article speaks about different measurement techniques accuracy vs. attraction range.

I can't find any information online on what "attraction range" means.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

It seems to me that attraction range means the area which is searched for an optimal solution, so that a wider range of search is more robust and a smaller range is riskier.  I'd appreciate confirmation of my understanding.

Comment: Have you looked at figure 4 and the description in the paper?

Comment: Yes, p.341 "... the attraction range [is then defined by] by the extent of the search 
space in which the initial offsets are reset to hC." It's the region where an initial incorrect guess will end up converging to hC rather than some other value.  As they note, since it's difficult to determine the exact boundary of this region in multi-dimensional space, they estimated it by just determining the boundary intersection with each of the dimensional axes.

Comment: @BryanKrause yes I looked at that figure and initially interpreted the attraction range as standard deviation.

Comment: @Armand thanks for pointing this out.